# How can diable x2apic mode when booting kernel via kexec

Tags: linux-kernel

When I boot kernel via kexec, it enables x2apic mode and causes my board does not reboot from external hardware NMI. Booting kernel from BIOS does not enable this mode and no issue happen in my board.

I am not sure whether in x2apic mode kernel can handle NMI successfully or not.

If anyone understands x2apic mode, could you explain it for me? And how can we disable x2apic mode when booting kernel via kexec.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I do not now enough about x2apic to tell you what it does, but to answer your second question, adding nox2apic as one of the kernel boot options disables it.

also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2APIC